# Show spinner while export is generated in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to be able to show a spinner while exported image is generated. 
Is there any way to achieve that, or an event i can subscribe to that fires when the file is generated and starts downloading?

My current code is

```
exporting: {
  allowHTML: true,
  buttons: {
  contextButton: {
    menuItems: null,
    onclick: function () {
      this.exportChart({ sourceWidth: 1500, sourceHeight: this.chartHeight }, null);
    },
    symbol: 'url(assets/images/icon_download.png)'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/uav1vjtv/

First 80 lines of code alter the Highcharts core. This modification implements `beforeExporting` and `afterExporting` events which can be used for managing the spinner icon (creating and destroying it):

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      beforeExporting: function() {
        this.spinner = this.renderer.image('http://thinkfuture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/loading_spinner.gif', this.chartWidth / 2 - 50, this.chartHeight / 2 - 50, 100, 100).add();
      },
      afterExporting: function() {
        this.spinner.destroy();
      }
    }
  }
```

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#image